# RTP sequence extract

Tags: c++, rtp

A RTP packet consists of a 12-byte RTP header and
subsequent RTP payload
The 3rd and 4th byte of the header contain the
Most-Significant-Byte and Least-Significant-Byte of
the sequence number of the RTP packet
Seq Num= (MSB<<8)+LSB

char pszPacket[12];

...

long lSeq = ???? - How to get the sequence number from a packet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
unsigned short seq = (packet[2] << 8) | packet[3];
```

Note that this assumes `packet` is an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: unsigned short is the correct type for 'seq', not (signed) long.  'char' vs 'unsigned char' doesn't matter for this set of operations (<< and |), though the RTP header should be an array of unsigned bytes.

Comment: On systems where `char` is signed, you'll get the wrong result whenever `packet[3]` is negative (since it will be sign-extended to `int` before being used as RHS of `|`).

Answer (score 3):

Surely thats just "long lSeq = (unsigned char)(pszPacket[2] << 8) | (unsigned char)pszPacket[3];"?

Comment: Additionally pszPacket should also be unsigned char[] and not plain char[].

Comment: Thank you! 

may be a little bracket fix:
long lSeq = ((unsigned char)pszPacket[2] << 8) | (unsigned char)pszPacket[3];

Comment: it doesn't really matter which way round .. but yeah if you prefer do it that way :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a proper implementation for that:

```
typedef struct _RTPHeader
{
  //first byte
#if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field */
  unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
  unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
  unsigned int         version:2;
#elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         version:2;
  unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
  unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
  unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field*/
#else
#error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
#endif
  //second byte
#if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         PT:7;     /* PT field */
  unsigned int         M:1;       /* M field */
#elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         M:1;         /* M field */
  unsigned int         PT:7;       /* PT field */
#else
#error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
#endif
  guint16              seq_num;      /* length of the recovery */
  guint32              TS;                   /* Timestamp */
  guint32              ssrc;
} RTPHeader; //12 bytes
```

And what you can do is:

```
char pszPacket[12];
RTPHeader* myRTPPacket = (RTPHeader*) pszPacket;
printf("Sequence number is: %hu", myRTPPacket->seq_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned __int16 seq = _rotr16( *( unsigned __int16* )&packet[2] , 8 );
```

Comment: That's completely dependent on the host's byte-order - if run on a little-endian system, you'll get the wrong result.

Comment: Rtp header is always written in big-endian byte order as it described in [RFC 3550 - RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time  Applications
](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550).

Comment: Exactly - so you'd need to transform the result using `ntohs()`.

Comment: unsigned __int16 seq = _rotr16( *( unsigned __int16* )&packet[2] , 8 ) - does the same .

Comment: Assuming that `_rotr16()` is Microsoft's compiler intrinsic, it's (a) non-portable, and (b) does exactly the wrong thing on big-endian hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have a pointer to a buffer of bytes that contains the whole RTP packet (including RTP header) called rtpBuffer, we can extract the 16 bit word in position 2 and 3 with the following code:

```
int8_t *rtpBuffer;

uint16_t packetSeqNbr = ntohs(*(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(rtpBuffer + 2)));
```

ntohs() is used to convert from network byte order to host byte order so that the code is portable to different machines.